# Проблему с подключением телевизора по hdmi

Tags: пк, hdmi

Подключаю телевизор по HDMI к стационарному компьютеру.
Видеокарта GeForce RTX 2060. Телевизор Haier 43 Smart TV. При попытке подключения телевизор пишет "Нет сигнала". Пк видит телевизор как доп. монитор.

Пробовал три разных кабеля, результат не меняется. При подключении кабеля к монитору изображение есть, следовательно hdmi на пк работает и кабель живой.

Чтобы проверить входной порт на телевизоре подключил связку ноутбук-телевизор, результат положителен все работает.

Пробовал менять расширение, удалять устройства, менять частоту - все бесполезно, связка пк-телевизор стабильно выдает "нет сигнала". Входной HDMI выбираю нужный) В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы выбираете в настройках телевизора источник сигнала?

Comment: Да, конечно. По HDMI не подключается вовсе. Display порт вылетает при попытке воспроизвести аудио на телевизоре. Заметил, что на всех устройствах, успешно работающих с телевизором видеокарта интегрированная, а на пк внешняя.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить драйвера на видеокарту до последней версии.

Comment: Вопрос не связан с программированием или администрированием ПО.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сменить кабель.
Часто проблема кроется в вышедшем из строя оборудовании и переферии.

Comment: Исключено. Три разных кабеля. Тем более в связке пк-монитор или ноутбук-телевизор все работает.